# get arabic value from icefaces's inputTextarea

Tags: jsf, unicode, character-encoding, icefaces

I am using icefaces when I enter arabic value I get some strange value like ????? on bean.

```
<ice:inputTextarea id="content" cols="30" rows="7"
    onkeypress="moveFocus(event,'btn-add');"
    binding="#{createSmsTemplateBean.bodyRef}"
    value="#{createSmsTemplateBean.smsTemplate.smsContent}"
    valueChangeListener="#{createSmsTemplateBean.contentChangeEvent}"
    partialSubmit="false"
    onkeyup="moveFocusSMS(event,'btn-addtag',form,this);"
    style="width: 507px; height: 97px;">
   </ice:inputTextarea>
```

when I print smsContent on createSmsTemplateBean, I got value like ?????.

i have also used meta tag in jspx like

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
```

still i get the problem....

Comment: Where exactly do you see `?????` ? In the log file? In the IDE console? In the webpage? In the database?

Comment: In the server log file i.e. i print that in System.out.println();

Comment: your file (.txt maybe) dosn't support arabic.

Comment: you have to check in the debugger, you should see the right chars...

Comment: take in mind, when you save somewhere the arabic chars (txt, db, xml, etc..) you have to be sure that your data source is using the UTF-8 enconding.

Comment: @chetan: use `@nickname` to notify others immediately about comments which are not been posted in their own message. Otherwise you're dependent on whether the other would decide to look in the question once again or not.

Comment: It is resolved , backside I get ????, but when I convert it into unicode it is work perfect.I will encode data into unicode while enter into database and decode that while fetch from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the output on server console as ????? but when i convert it to char ascii it converted fine i.e this is problem of sever log file console that it can not display such character